# ECS (EC2 type) task is failing container health check, but ALB health check works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition

I have ECS cluster (EC2 type, 1 service only) with ALB and Target Group. Desired count is set to 2 on ECS service level, no ASG for tasks. Technically everything works. I can communicate with my API without  any problem, but there is a small issue that bothers me. Container health check for my ECS tasks doesn't work. I'm mapping container port 3000 to host port 0, but since it's inside container it shouldn't matter?

I'm struggling to understand why, here is the cmd I use (I will just paste my whole health check block since I'm using terraform to deploy my infra)

```
healthCheck = {
    retries = 10
    command = ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:3000/health || exit 1"]
    timeout : 5
    interval : 10
    startPeriod : 45
}
```

I's worth mentioning that both my task with random ports are visible in Target Group health check, where I'm using the same endpoint. Here is how it looks like:

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "my_api_backend_tg" {
  name                 = "my_tg_name"
  port                 = 3000
  protocol             = "HTTP"
  vpc_id               = "vpc_id"
  deregistration_delay = 25

  health_check {
    path                = "/health"
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 5
    timeout             = 5
    interval            = 15
    matcher             = "200"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
    ignore_changes        = [name]
  }
}
```

I'm relatively new to AWS, so it might be trivial, but I'm not even sure how can I debug it, would appreciate any help.

Comment: What are the target group health check settings?

Comment: TG resource looks like this:
`resource "aws_alb_target_group" "my_api_backend_tg" {port= 3000 protocol =http health_check { path = "/health" healthy_threshold  = 2 unhealthy_threshold = 5 timeout = 5 interval = 15 matcher = "200" }}`

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, it is unreadable. You can edit your original question to add more information like this.

Answer (score 4):

After all it was something trivial and not even related to AWS, but to docker itself. Image was so thin that there was no curl installed. Installing it fixed my problem.

Comment: You save the day!